# Make specific network drive unavailable for offline files

Tags: windows-7, offline-files

I want to disable the ability for people to make certain network drives available offline, but not remove the permission entirely.  I know offline files can be disabled entirely in group policy, but can you deny permission on a per-drive (mapped network drive) basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your host/server this can be a per share option. Instead of looking at it from the client side look at it from the server side. O: leads to \SERVER\Share. Look at that shares properties. There is generally options in there to change the Offline ability.

Comment: Found it under the folder properties > sharing settings.  Thank you.